# Why "hjkl" is highly recommended?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VimTutor arrow keys v/s hjkl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708753/vimtutor-arrow-keys-v-s-hjkl)

Why ["hjkl" is highly recommended](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Learn-Vim-Progressively/)?

I think it's more convenice using arrow key.

Is there any advantages using "hjkl"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit like using the mouse. Every time you reach the mouse, or the arrow keys, you have to move your hand back to the main part of the keyboard to access other very common commands like <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> and you will lose some time.

Rather than the time, I think that the main issue is you are losing some focus on what you are doing, because you have to look at (or think about) your hand rather than the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You **keep your fingers on the home row** and if you're using **touch typing** (which you should) you are **much faster at editing**.

Check [**this page**](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/) to get more info.

Comment: I've read [this page](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/) before, but I'm still confused.Thanks anyway!